# Add extra time to the wso2 JWT exp claim

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

The unix timestamp on our exp claim is always just the current time, and we would like it to be 15 minutes ahead, like expires in 15 minutes. We tried setting the validity period to 900 in the API store, but that doesn't seem to affect the JWT. Is there a way to alter the JWT default claims in wso2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `<EnableGatewayTokenCache>` or `<EnableKeyManagerTokenCache>` elements are enabled in the `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/api-manager.xml` file, the expiry time of the JWT is the same as the cache expiry time by default.
However, if caching is not enabled for the Gateway and Key Manager nodes, the JWT expiry time can be set by adding the expiry time in minutes in the `<JWTClaimCacheExpiry>` element of the `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/api-manager.xml` file. For example,

```
<CacheConfigurations>
     ....
     <JWTClaimCacheExpiry>60</JWTClaimCacheExpiry>
     ....
</CacheConfigurations>
```

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Passing+Enduser+Attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT#PassingEnduserAttributestotheBackendUsingJWT-SettingtheexpirytimeoftheJWT